# How can I post my Delicious bookmarks on my Facebook wall?

Tags: bookmarks, facebook, delicious

I want to post a bookmark link in Delicious on my Facebook wall, when I save it in Delicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Facebook Apps that claim to do post your delicious bookmarks to facebook:

- [del.icio.us box](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=47595357651)
- [My del.icio.us](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=9615235559&v=info)

Comment: both of links do not work.

Comment: horrible ratings on both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I use [RSS Graffiti](http://www.rssgraffiti.com), a Facebook app for posting RSS feeds to your wall / timeline.
It works but is inconsistent about how often it updates. Hopefully delicious itself, now that it's back from the dead, will develop a Facebook app for this.